# Django settings values from a Database table

Tags: django, django-settings, django-endless-pagination

Is it possible to set the values for the variables in settings.py from a database table?

I'm using [`endless_pagination`](http://code.google.com/p/django-endless-pagination/) and it has a overwrite-able setting

`ENDLESS_PAGINATION_PER_PAGE = 10`,

I need to set this value with a value from my database table, is it possible?

like

```
config = Config.objects.get(param_name__exact="ENDLESS_PAGINATION_PER_PAGE") 
settings.ENDLESS_PAGINATION_PER_PAGE= config.param_value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their documentation, this variable can be overwritten by your template tag:

```
{% paginate objects %}
{% paginate 20 objects %} {# makes it 20 per page #}
```

Source: http://code.google.com/p/django-endless-pagination/source/browse/endless_pagination/templatetags/endless.py

Update: using this fact, you can set a variable in your View which gets passed to the template:

```
{% paginate my_pagination_count objects %}
```